# Why do we see the Community account so less frequently here?

Tags: discussion

On some websites like Stack Overflow the [Community account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) is there on nearly every bad question. But seeing it here is a truly rare sight. Makes me wonder that it is really a robot!

Comment: Probably because the community (humans) are doing a better job than the community (a background process).

Answer (score 5):

The Community account is automated scripting.  Community will bump old questions, delete questions meeting certain criteria, will show up as the editing user for anonymous edits and in a few other scenarios.

You see that user less here because:

- lower question volume
- less anonymous editing
- less need for cleanup deletions
- fewer unanswered questions needing bumps

For more information on what community does and can do, [see the main meta site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/167163)